# Populating a model with MembershipUser and Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I have created a model `UserModel` that holds `MembershipUser` and `string[] Roles` for each user. In my controller I'm trying to return an `IEnumerable<UserModel>` to the view but running into issues.

> Cannot convert source type '`IEnumerable<{user:MembershipUser, roles:string[]}>`' to target type '`IEnumerable<UserModel>`'

My Model

```
public class UserModel {
    public MembershipUser user { get; set; }
    public string[] roles { get; set; }
}
```

And in my controller

```
public ActionResult Users() {
    IEnumerable<UserModel> model = from MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers()
                select new {user = u, roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName)};

    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are selecting an anonymous type when I think you want your `UserModel`.

```
public ActionResult Users() {
    IEnumerable<UserModel> model = from MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers()
                select new UserModel {user = u, roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName)};

    return View(model);
}
```